# Use the fact that $\ln(1+x) \leq x$ to show that $(a_1a_2\cdot\cdot\cdot a_n)^{1/n} \leq \frac{a_1+a_2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+a_n}{n}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The question starts off by saying, show that $\ln(1+x) \leq x$ which is easy enough.

But then it says, by making an appropriate choice of x, hence prove that:

$(a_1a_2\cdot\cdot\cdot a_n)^{1/n} \leq \frac{a_1+a_2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+a_n}{n}$

The way I tried it is letting $x=a_1a_2...a_n-1$

Then,

$\ln(a_1a_2\cdot\cdot\cdot a_n) \leq a_1a_2\cdot\cdot\cdot a_n-1$

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{n}$

$\ln((a_1a_2...a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}) \leq \frac{a_1a_2\cdot\cdot\cdot a_n-1}{n}$

Raising both sides to e

$(a_1a_2...a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq e^{\frac{a_1a_2...a_n-1}{n}}$

We get the RHS of the wanted result but other than that everything is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asserting $\ln(1+x)\leqslant x$ is the same thing as asserting that $x+1\leqslant e^x$, which, in term, is the same thing as saying that $x=(x-1)+1\leqslant e^{x-1}$.

Now, let $m=\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}n$. We may assume that each $a_k$ is greater than $0$. Then the previous inequality tells us that\begin{align}\frac{a_1}m\times\frac{a_2}m\times\cdots\times\frac{a_n}m&\leqslant\exp\left(\frac{a_1}m-1\right)\exp\left(\frac{a_2}m-1\right)\cdots\exp\left(\frac{a_n}m-1\right)\\&=\exp\left(\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}m-n\right)\\&=\exp(n-n)\\&=1.\end{align}This means, of course, that$$a_1a_2\cdots a_n\leqslant m^n,$$which, in turn, means that$$\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}\leqslant\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}n.$$

Comment: After the point you said. "Then the previous inequality tells us that..." You introduce these inequalities, I do not quite understand how those came about, otherwise I understand the rest.

Comment: I am just using the fact that $$\frac{a_k}m\leqslant e^{\frac{a_k}m-1},$$for each $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: Oh so essentially you made many of those inequalities individually and multiplied them all together to produce the one you made?

Comment: Yes, that's indeed what I did! Is it all clear now?

Comment: Yes, thank you.